# why the Button changing position onClick?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, button

I am building a TicTacToe using React Hook. While the TicTacToe is working fine, the buttons are changing position on click. Image 1 is the initial game board, and image 2 is after clicking on the button! it is going down. If I click on consecutive three buttons it goes to the previous position (image 3).

tictactoe

[image: tictactoe]

I don't want the buttons to change the position.

my code is like below:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

    import Square from './Square';
    function Board(){
        const [boardSquares, setBoardSquares] = useState(Array(9).fill(null));
        const [xIsNext, setXIsNext] = useState(true);

        const handleClick = index =>{
            const squares = [...boardSquares]; 

            if( whoIsTheWinner(boardSquares) || squares[index]) return;       
            squares[index] = xIsNext ? "X" : "O";
            setBoardSquares(squares);
            setXIsNext(!xIsNext);


        };
           const renderSquare = (index) => {
            return <Square value={boardSquares[index]} onClick={()=>handleClick(index)}/>
        };
       let status ;
        const winner = whoIsTheWinner(boardSquares);

        status = winner ? 
        `Winner is: ${winner}` :
        `Next player: ${xIsNext ? "X" : "O"}`; 

        function whoIsTheWinner(squares){
                const winningLine = [
                    [0, 1, 2],
                    [0, 3, 6],
                    [0, 4, 8],
                    [1, 4, 7],
                    [2, 5, 8],
                    [3, 4, 5],
                    [6, 7, 8],
                    [0, 4, 8]
                   ];
                   console.log(winningLine)
                   for (let i=0; i < winningLine.length; i++){
                       const [a,b,c]=winningLine[i];
                       if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[b]===squares[c])
                       return squares[a]; 
                   } 

                return null;
                };

        return(
            <div>
                <div>               
                   {status}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {renderSquare(0)}
                    {renderSquare(1)}
                    {renderSquare(2)}
                </div> 
                <div>
                    {renderSquare(3)}
                    {renderSquare(4)}
                    {renderSquare(5)}
                </div> 
                <div>
                    {renderSquare(6)}
                    {renderSquare(7)}
                    {renderSquare(8)}
                </div>  

            </div>
        );
    }

    export default Board;
```

the CSS code is:

```
.button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.button:active {
  background-color: grey;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: palegreen;
}
```

Comment: Put up a working snippet

Comment: The space looks like the same size of you X/O, just saying... A working stackblitz or something would be nice to test your code please

Comment: I see css for a `.button` class but I don't see anywhere the class is actually used. Include the button code if that's what's moving unexpectedly.

Comment: Edit your question and click on the Create Snippit button, 7th button from the left in your body section. Add a working snippit of your issue. Include all relevant code so others can help assist with the issue.

Comment: It might help to see your `<Square/>` component and any styles you are applying to it.

Answer (score 0):

I also come to this trouble and have narrowed it down to because of empty text in the button. If the button text were not empty the button position wouldn't move after a click for a reason that I still don't understand.

the workaround for the problem:

```
    function Board(){
        ....
        ....Array(9).fill("\0"));
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to the display of your Square components. To solve it, you'll need to modify the CSS properties of your Square component.

Navigate to the CSS file of your Square component.

Look at the CSS properties that you have affected to the class `.button` of your Square component buttons. It should include the `float:left;` property as below:

```
.button {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: greenyellow;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

Also make sure that you import your Square CSS file into your Square component JS file.